# PyCharm can't connect to database and load it to Pandas?

Tags: python, machine-learning, syntax, pycharm

I have SQL Server DB which I want to connect and fetch data from in order to run PCA and other machine learning tasks to predict some target variables.

I have installed PyCharm and started to importing the packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pypyodbc

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://username:pwd@myserver/DBName')
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
"C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\python.exe" C:/Users/BeehiveDev04/.PyCharmCE2017.1/config/scratches/scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BeehiveDev04/.PyCharmCE2017.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pypyodbc
ImportError: No module named pypyodbc
```

When I have run: `conda install -c anaconda pyodbc=4.0.16`

I still get error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Please advice what should I do, what do I miss here?

Comment: Where do you run `conda install...`?

Comment: In the Python console at the bottom of the Pycharm

Comment: `conda install...` needs to be run from the command line, not from within Python console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to note there is a difference between *importing* a package, and *installing* a package. Before using any modules in your Python script, they must first be installed. This can be done in a few ways:

1. Open the command line and type in `conda install package_name`
2. If not using Anaconda then type in `pip install package_name` (make sure Python is in your PATH).
3. Pycharm allows you to install packages by going to File -> settings -> project -> project interpreter and entering the desired package name.

Once packages have been installed correctly then you can *import* them in your Python script